# Determining the inverse function

Tags: functions

I need to determine the inverse function for the following function:

$$
f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\ \ \ \text{with}\ \ f(x)=x^2\\
\text{so I need to determine}\\
f^{-1}(\{25\})
$$

So I know that the function $f(x)=x^2$ is bijective, so it has a inverse.

I was thinking to do the assignment, in the following manner:
$$
\text{find the inverse of $f(x)=x^2$}\\
y=x^2\\
\pm\sqrt{y}=x\\
f^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{x}\\
\text{now that I have the inverse function, I can put $25$ inside, so I get:}\\
f^{-1}(\{25\})=\pm5\\
$$

Did I do this right? Any advice appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The function has no inverse, because it's not injective.

Comment: I believe you want *inverse image* (or preimage); nothing to do with inverse functions!

Comment: As the OP shows, he wants the inverse image as the argument to $f^{-1}$ is a set and not a number. Just imprecise use of language but his mathematical notation is quite precise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, except your teacher may want you to write the answer out in a set form, i.e
$$
f^{-1}({25}) = \{5, -5\}
$$
$\pm 5$ is just a shorthand when writing out solutions, not sets.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not bijective (f(-5)=f(5)=25).
Considere the induced function $R^+ \leftarrow R^+$ which is bijective